# How to deal with not nullable navigation properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two classes:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class Document
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    }
```

I want that when creating (for example with swagger) Employee if at least one Document was not provided it occured an exception.

```
{
  "name": "Victor",
  "documents": [
    {
      "serialNumber": "12345"
    }
  ]
}
// must give 200OK
{
  "name": "Victor"
}
// must give error
```

I've tried to configure them in FluentApi:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Documents)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.EmployeeId)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
            .HasOne<Employee>()
            .WithMany(e => e.Documents)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.EmployeeId)
            .IsRequired();
```

But even if i dont provide document Employee is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fluent API configuration is used to configure the relationships between entities and their properties. However, it does not validate the data that is input when creating or updating entities.

To achieve the validation you are looking for, you can add validation attributes to the Employee class properties. Specifically, you can add the [Required] attribute to the Documents property to ensure that at least one document is required when creating an employee.

You should also include the Key attribute so that EF knows that this is going to be the primary key for that table. And then add the ForiegnKey attribute to EmloyeeId, this will tell EF about that relationship.

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Documents are required.")]
    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Employee")]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```